# CRS problems with SwtMapPane

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

I'm quite new to geotools and I'm trying to get to grips with it.
Trying to load some shapefiles (see attachment) into a `MapContent` which in turn 
is associated with a `SwtMapPane` I always get an exception that suggests that 
there's something wrong with the current CRS of the map pane:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument "sourceCRS" should not be null.
        at 
org.geotools.referencing.operation.AbstractCoordinateOperationFactory.ensureNonNull(AbstractCoordinateOperationFactory.java:734)
        at 
org.geotools.referencing.operation.BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.createOperation(BufferedCoordinateOperationFactory.java:249)
        at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.findMathTransform(CRS.java:1205)
        at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.findMathTransform(CRS.java:1173)
        at org.geotools.swt.SwtMapPane.setCrs(SwtMapPane.java:436)
        at org.geotools.swt.SwtMapPane.layerAdded(SwtMapPane.java:812)
        at org.geotools.map.MapContent.fireLayerAdded(MapContent.java:468)
        at 
org.geotools.map.MapContent$LayerList.addIfAbsent(MapContent.java:1063)
        at org.geotools.map.MapContent.addLayer(MapContent.java:369)
        at org.geotools.JSurveyMvn.App.fileOpen(App.java:87)
        at org.geotools.JSurveyMvn.App$1.widgetSelected(App.java:113)
        at 
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3540)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3161)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
        at org.geotools.JSurveyMvn.App.<init>(App.java:47)
        at org.geotools.JSurveyMvn.App.main(App.java:58)
```

When trying to explicitly set a CRS directly after associating the (empty) 
`MapContent` to the map pane (see line 149), I'll get a `NullPointerException` like that:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.geotools.swt.SwtMapPane.setCrs(SwtMapPane.java:433)
        at org.geotools.JSurveyMvn.App.createContents(App.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:431)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:790)
        at org.geotools.JSurveyMvn.App.<init>(App.java:47)
        at org.geotools.JSurveyMvn.App.main(App.java:58)
```

I'm quite desperate of being unable to solve that problem. Can you please give  me a hand to make it work?

Obviously it's not possible to attach files here. So here's my original post to the Geotools-gt2-users list which seems to be inactive but allows adding code and map samples: http://sourceforge.net/p/geotools/mailman/message/34635944/ Attached is the source code of an example application that demonstrates the  problem (run under linux (amd64) using getools v. 13.3 or 14.0) as well as the shapefile.

Comment: please paste the relevant piece of code (preferably the shortest working example) that shows the error into the question

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it might be that you did not set the **display area** beforehand:

```
mySwtMapPane.setDisplayArea(<BBOX>);
mySwtMapPane.setCrs(<CRS>);
```

If you look at the `SwtMapPane#setCrs()`, you see that it triggers the recomputations of the internal `screen<-->world` transforms, which require having set a .. screen area:

```
430  ReferencedEnvelope rEnv = getDisplayArea();
     [...]
433  CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = rEnv.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
```

(your `rEnv` is throwing the NPE)